# Encryption/Decryption for Salesforce Integration with Other Systems by WebServices

Tags: integration, webservices, encryption

I have to expose a synchronous ws that allows to acquire the same message sometimes encrypted and sometimes not. How should I do the WS? examples of outbound WS for cryptography?

Please Help me ....

Comment: Your original question received both answers and some discussion. You really should edit your original question to make it more specific rather than asking another nonspecific question. You have not provided enough information to formulate answers or discussion.

Comment: Sorry. I immediately change the original message. I'm new to the forum and I thought I had to write a new question asking for different info.